# Can python NOT replace '\n' by default?

Tags: python, http, post, mender

I am working with Python. Currently creating an API to get information from Mender.

I want to send a post request. In my body one of the parameter got ***'\n'*** symbol. I **WANT** it to stay that way otherwise my request won't work.
This is a new line symbol I do not want it to be escaped as a character.

Here is my code.
If I print my argument before creating the 'data' object it prints '\n' as expected.
BUT if I print my 'data' object all my '\n' had been transformed into '\\n' so when I dump my 'data' object my '\n' are now '\\\\n'.

```
    data = {
    "identity_data": {
        "mac": args.mac_address,
        "sku": args.sku
    },
    "pubkey": args.public_key,
    "tenant_token": args.tenant_token
}
print(data)

data = json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")
api.deviceauth.create(headers=headers, data=data)
```

Please is there a way to avoid this default behavior of Python ? how Am I supposed to send new line symbol in a post request ? 
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

try using r'......\n' the r tells python to process it in raw form rather than considering escape sequence.

Comment: Although it seems to be EXACTLY what I want I tried to replace  `"pubkey": args.public_key,` inside my 'data' object by `"pubkey": fr'{args.public_key}'` But I still observe the same result...